# Undefined return type in Go

Tags: go, mux

I'm fairly new to Go and am having trouble with a code snippet that uses mux-gorilla sessions/cookies. There is a lot of redundancy that I would like to reduce with the following function:

```
func isLoggedIn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (bool, *Session) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, "user")
    var logged bool = true
    if err != nil { // Need to delete the cookie.
        expired := &http.Cookie{Path: "/", Name: "user", MaxAge: -1, Expires: time.Now().Add(-100 * time.Hour)}
        http.SetCookie(w, expired)
        logged := false
    }
    return logged, session
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following compilation error: `undefined: Session`

How can this type be undefined if it can be returned by the store.Get function? Note that store was declared before as `store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(secret))`, using the "gorilla/sessions" package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go needs to know which package to find `Session` in: `sessions.Session`.

The error is on the signature of your func `isLoggedIn`

So your modified code would be:

```
import "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
func isLoggedIn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (bool, *sessions.Session) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: So If I have a function that returns a type that isn't imported yet.. as long as I don't specifically use that type, I don't need to anyway?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question; if you specifically name the type (as you have in your function signature), you have to include the import

Comment: If you never explicitly name the type (i.e. in the function signature, or elsewhere), you can use the returned value without the import.

Comment: Yes yes, you are correct. I'm just trying to figure out where I don't need to use the import. For example, when my code was still very redundant, I was simply using the store.Get function directly, and did not need to use the import statement.

Comment: You only need to do an import when you want to directly refer to the type in your code.  because store.Get returns a sessions.Session, the local variable can be inferred in isLoggedIn.  But if you want to return it, or create a new instance of sessions.Session, you need to perform the import.  Basically, if you source code mentions the package, you must import it.

Comment: And, any type not defined in your package, must be prefixed with the package. (exception being . imports, but don't use those)